# duplicate entry: com/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultRenderersFactory.class

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

i'm getting this error when im trying to generate an APK.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     com/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultRenderersFactory.class

This is my gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.2'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'

compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.13.3@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

// From Finwe maven repo at Bintray
compile ('fi.finwe.orion360:orion360-sdk-pro:3.1.02.001'){
    exclude module: 'exoplayer2'
}

// Debug version of FinweUtil enables debug logs from Orion360.
debugCompile ('fi.finwe.util:finwe-util:1.0.04-debug'){
    exclude module: 'exoplayer2'
}

// Release version of FinweUtil should be used for all releases (no debug logs).
releaseCompile ('fi.finwe.util:finwe-util:1.0.04'){
    exclude module: 'exoplayer2'
}

//ExoPlayer as an alternative video engine.
compile ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.2'){
    exclude module: 'exoplayer2'
}

compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp-integration:1.4.0'
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
compile project(':library')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
}
```

I have tried several solutions that i found, but nothing worked. Any help would be much appreciated .